# Has the homology of the Baumslag Solitar groups B(1,k) been computed?

Tags: group-theory, group-cohomology, combinatorial-group-theory

I'm trying to compute some homology for related groups and was wondering if the homology of these groups have been studied. Using the description of these groups as semidirect products of $\mathbb{Z}[1/k] \ltimes_k \mathbb{Z}$, I thought this would just pop out from the Lyndon-Hothschild-Serre spectral sequence, but I'm finding it a bit more difficult.

Comment: Torsion-free one relator groups are known to be aspherical, and so have cohomological dimension $1$ or $2$. Hence, every Baumslag-Solitar group has homological dimension $\leq2+1=3$. (Possibly viewing them as HNN-extensions of $\mathbb{Z}$ rather than semidirect products may be more fruitful, via [this](https://eudml.org/doc/172217) paper of Bieri.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By Magnus(-Karrass-Solitar) theorem, one-relator group only has torison in case its relator is a proper power. Then, by Cockroft's theorem (*W. H. Cockroft, On two-dimesional alpherical complexes*, 1954, rediscovered later by Lyndon and other people, see, for example, "Lyndon Identity theorem"), presentation complex of a torsion-free one-relator group is aspherical, so it is a classifying space for that group.

So... we're lucky, because we can use explicit cellular structure of presentation complex — which happens to be $K(G, 1)$ — to compute (co)homology. Cellular complex for $BS(r, s)$ will be
$$\Bbb Z \overset{(0, r-s)}\longrightarrow \Bbb Z^2 \overset{0}\longrightarrow \Bbb Z$$

So, $H_1$ is $\Bbb Z \oplus \Bbb Z/(r-s)$ (which is already clear from presentation), and $H_2$ is zero. Turns out there's not much to study after all.

I want to remark that vanishing of $H_2$ can be obtained without (pretty hard) asphericity result. To make a classifying space out of presentation complex, we only add cells in dimensions 3 and higher, but that can only kill 2-dim homology classes, not add new ones. Now we notice that cellular differential should be nonzero on (the only) 2-cell of presentation complex (because it's a 2-generated group with rank 1 abelianization, and we need *something* to kill a 1-dim cycle). Same reasoning tells us that $k$-generated $(k-l)$-relator group with abelianisation having rank $l$ will have vanishing $H_2$.

///

A different avenue for calculating homology would be using "Mayer-Vietoris" sequence from *I. M. Chiswell. Exact sequences associated with a graph of
groups* — especially if you want to compute homology with nontrivial coefficients.

P. S. I vaguely remember a paper by D. J. S. Robinson, where he computers homology of more general graphs of groups with cyclic edge and vertex groups, but cannot remember the title. It would be interesting to know homology of "cyclic BS-type" groups, like Higman group - i. e. you have generators indexed by $\Bbb Z/n$, and $i$-th generator conjugates the $i+1$-st one into some power. Relation modules of presentations of this type occurred in potential (counter)examples to the relation gap conjecture.

Comment: +! nice answer! Unlike their book, the proper power result has the normal attribution: A. Karrass, W. Magnus, and D. Solitar, *Elements of finite order in groups with a single defining relation,* Comm. on Pure App. Math. 13 (1960), no. 1, 57–66. (in other words, "Magnus(-Karrass-Solitar)" should really be "Karrass-Magnus-Solitar").

Comment: Also, just to check: $H_2$ is only $0$ for (torsion-free) two-generator, one-relator groups, as $b_2=2-\#\text{gens}$?

Comment: @user1729 About $H_2$: I wanted to emphasise that we can prove vanishing even if we do not know that presentation complex is aspherical. (I added that to my answer to replace vague Euler characteristic remark). About attribution: proper power result can be pretty easily derived from Freiheitssatz — so I would qualify Magnus as a *first author* (:

Comment: Hmm, I'm unconvinced by the "easy derivation", in the sense that it is straightforward now, using modern machinery and viewpoints, but its 4 pages in their book (which from memory closely reflects their paper). Moreover, there is more to a result than the proof - someone must "see" the result first, etc.

Comment: Asphericity for this example is very easy to verify by direct construction: the universal cover is homeomorphic to the product of $\mathbb R$ with a tree having valence $3$ at every vertex; the product of two contractible spaces is contractible.